# Set/change Docker virtual machine limits in Windows

Tags: docker, memory, resources, cpu

I am looking for a way to change [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/janJVl.png) Docker settings from a command line interface without admin credentials (and to restart the docker service).

Is this possible out of the box?
Note that this is the setting for the *virtual machine* itself, so assigning `--memory=""` to a container will not help in this case.

I looked into `Set-VM` commands in Windows but could not properly restart docker with those while keeping all network connections working.

--

Windows 10 ( build 16299.19)
Version 17.09.0-ce-win33 (13620)

Answer (score 0):

If it's running as admin, you will be required to have those creds. You can't just change something a higher priv user runs.

Comment: I assume it's not running as admin because I can change options with the GUI on a restricted user profile.